# Solspace calendar all day event time

Tags: solspace, solspace-calendar

When you add a calendar event using Solspace calendar you have the option of inputting the times or selecting the check box 'all day event'. Currently the all day event times show as 12am-12pm. Is there any way of changing this? For example I would like the all day event check box time to be 8am-6pm.

Thanks,
Julie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The option **all day event** is intended for a event to not have a specific starting or ending time. To prove that, you can take a look at the database:

```
SELECT * FROM exp_calendar_events WHERE all_day = "y";
```

When the user set an event as "all day", the saved start_time and end_time in database is 0.

So, no, you can't change this, but you can show different time on you template. If you are, for example, using [the `calendar:events` variable pair](http://www.solspace.com/docs/calendar/events/), you can do this:

```
{if event_all_day}8am-6pm{if:else}{event_start_date format="%h%a"}-{event_end_date format="%h%a"}{/if}
```

I hope it helps.